# Bresenham Vs Midpoint Circle drawing algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithms, c, graphics

Can somebody explain the difference between Bresenham and Midpoint Circle drawing algorithms? All I am able to understand is that in both algorithms we compute coordinates of an octant instead of whole Circle and in Midpoint algo we compute those coordinates by putting middle point of the 2 possible next coordinates in Circle equation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is easily found with a search engine.

Comment: @ScantRoger: the question does not show any effort of research, of course, but in general, it fits to what is on-topic here on "Programmers".

Comment: @ScantRoger **[A Close Vote is not a Super-Downvote. Please don't use it as one](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5498)**

Answer (score 2):

**Bresenham's algorithm** deals with integers, so is very less time and memory consuming.This algorithm is accurate and efficient as it avoids using round function or floating point calculations.
**Mid-point circle algorithm** also avoids square root or trigonometric calculation by adopting integer operation only. This algorithm checks the nearest integer by calculating the midpoint of the pixels nearer to the given point on the circle.

Answer (score -1):

Bresenham's circle algorithm is modified version of mid point circle algorithm with different value of producing parameter.

Comment: this seems to merely repeat points already made and explained in  [prior answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/303840/31260) that was posted over two years ago

Comment: this is summary in short